# C++/CLI from tracking reference to (native) reference - wrapping

Tags: reference, c++-cli, clr, pass-by-reference, managed

I need a C# interface to call some native C++ code via the CLI dialect. The C# interface uses the *out* attribute specifier in front of the required parameters. That translates to a *%* tracking reference in C++/CLI.

The method I has the following signature and body (it is calling another native method to do the job):

```
virtual void __clrcall GetMetrics(unsigned int %width, unsigned int %height, unsigned int %colourDepth, int %left, int %top) sealed
{
    mRenderWindow->getMetrics(width, height, colourDepth, left, top);
}
```

Now the code won't compile because of a few compile time errors (all being related to `not being able to convert parameter 1 from 'unsigned int' to 'unsigned int &'`).

As a modest C++ programmer, to me CLI is looking like Dutch to a German speaker. What can be done to make this wrapper work properly in CLI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like it was also suggested in a deleted answer, I did the obvious and used local variables to pass the relevant values around:

```
 virtual void __clrcall GetMetrics(unsigned int %width, unsigned int %height, unsigned int %colourDepth, int %left, int %top) sealed
        {
            unsigned int w = width, h = height, c = colourDepth;
            int l = left, t = top;
            mRenderWindow->getMetrics(w, h, c, l, t);
            width = w; height = h; colourDepth = c; left = l; top = t;
        }
```

It was a bit obvious since the rather intuitive mechanism of tracked references: they're affected by the garbage collector's work and are not really that static/constant as normal `&`references when they're prone to be put somewhere else in memory. Thus this is the only way reliable enough to overcome the issue. Thanks to the initial answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your parameters use 'out' on the C# side, you need to define your C++/CLI parameters like this: `[Out] unsigned int ^%width`

Here's an example:

```
virtual void __clrcall GetMetrics([Out] unsigned int ^%width)
{
    width = gcnew UInt32(42);
}
```

Then on your C# side, you'll get back 42:

```
ValueType vt;
var res = cppClass.GetMetrics(out vt);
//vt == 42
```

In order to use the [Out] parameter on the C++/CLI side you'll need to include:

```
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, oddly enough it did not compile the first time I tried it (and it doesn't now! Compiler error). And yes, in the C# interface, the reference parameters have the _out_ attribute in front of them. But this resolved to just putting the `%` tracked ref operator in front of them (it was also the way the compiler suggested doing it - although I tried with the System::Runtime::InteropServices::Out attribute. The problem is that I need to pass `width` to a normal native C++ routine. That's not going to work (see my error message about a failed conversion). Cheers!

Comment: Boxing value type values is a Really Bad Idea.  Nor does it solve the OP's problem.

Comment: Answer update (thanks to @HansPassant's suggestion and initial explanation). +1

Comment: I knew that was the issue, but thought it was too obvious to even mention. Ofcourse you can't directly pass managed variables to a native C++ function :) Well I'm glad it works!

Comment: Thanks, it does work, even if it looks like an odd way to scratch your head.. :).

Answer (score 0):

You can use pin_ptr so that 'width' doesn't move when native code changes it. The managed side suffers from pin_ptr, but I don't think you can get around that if you want native code directly access it without 'w'.

```
virtual void __clrcall GetMetrics(unsigned int %width, unsigned int %height, unsigned int %colourDepth, int %left, int %top) sealed
        {
            pin_ptr<unsigned int> pw = &width; //do the same for height
            mRenderWindow->getMetrics(*pw, h, c, l, t);
        }
```